# Implications of a Regularity Condition for Functions

Tags: integration, measurable-functions

$
    \newcommand{\essSup}{\mathop{\rm sup_{ess}}\nolimits}
  $

What can be concluded from the fact, that $f: X\ni x\mapsto f(x)\in [a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}\setminus\lbrace{-\infty,+\infty\rbrace} $ has the following property:

$$ f(x_0) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \essSup\left(f\left(x\in X\cap U_\epsilon\left(x_0\right)\right)\right)$$

> **Questions:**
>
> - are such functions Riemann integrable, and if not,
> - what are examples of such functions, that are not Riemann integrable?

Comment: I am not sure about the tagging, so please feel free to correct.

Comment: Tags are ok --maybe "real-analysis" also fits. (The meaning of the third question is not quite clear, though).

Comment: @PietroMajer thanks for the feedback; I just realized that the 3rd question was based on a misconception, so I removed it. I'm a bit hesitant about setting the "real-analysis" because $X$ isn't restricted to $\mathbb{R}$, but could also be a function space, thus relating the question to functional analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example: the characteristic function of a fat Cantor set (a compact nowhere dense set of positive Lebesgue measure): it is upper semicontinuous, so the equality holds; it has a positive set of discontinuities, thus it is not Riemann integrable.